# Boost.Asio async_read on serial port completes unexpectedly?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using Boost.Asio to communicate with a device through RS232.  I send a command with `boost::asio::write()`, and then wait for an answer with `boost::asio::async_read()` and a `boost::asio::transfer_at_least(6)` completion condition.  Sometimes the read operation completes with success and `6` bytes of data are read.  However, there are other times where the read operations unexpectedly completes immediately with success and `0` bytes transferred.

My understanding is that the completion condition `transfer_at_least` should prevent the read operation from completing until `6` bytes have been read.  It apparently doesn't... Why?  My temporary solution is to read again from the serial port if there are no bytes transferred.  It seems a nasty solution to me.

I'm using the following functions integrated in a class:

```
void SerialPort::do_read()
{
  printf("reading feedback on the serial port \n");
  boost::asio::async_read(port,boost::asio::buffer(&buffer_read,6), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(6), boost::bind(&SerialPort::read_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

  timeout_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(SERIAL_TIMEOUT_MS));
  timeout_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SerialPort::wait_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

  printf("start event loop\n");
  io_service.run();
  printf("close event loop \n..................\n");
  ready_to_write = true;
}

void SerialPort::read_callback(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{  
  //*** DEBUG
  printf("Function read_callback\n");
  if(!error) 
    cout << "Error Code: " << error.message() <<endl;

  cout << "Bytes transferred: " << bytes_transferred << endl;
  //***

  if(!error && bytes_transferred == 0)
  {
    //boost::asio::async_read(port,boost::asio::buffer(&buffer_read,6), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(6), boost::bind(&SerialPort::read_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    printf("Serial Link : No data to read.\n");
    return;
  }

  if(error)
  {
    printf("Serial Link : Error when reading data.\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("Going to cancel the timer\n");
  timeout_timer.cancel();  // will cause wait_callback to fire with an error boost::asio::error::operation_aborted
  printf("%u %u %u %u %u %u\n", buffer_read[0], buffer_read[1], buffer_read[2], buffer_read[3], buffer_read[4], buffer_read[5]);
  return;
}

void SerialPort::wait_callback(const boost::system::error_code& error) //Called when the timer's deadline expire
{
  if (error)
  {
    printf("Timeout cancelled.\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("Timeout fired.\n");
  timer_has_fired = true;
  printf("Going to cancel the serial port \n");
  port.cancel();  // Close all asynchronous operation with serial port. will cause read_callback to fire with an error
  printf("All operations on serial port cancelled.\n");
  return;
}
```

And `buffer_read` is a member of the class, created in my header file:

```
unsigned char buffer_read[6];
```

When handler tracking is enabled and the program is working fine, I get the following output:

```
@asio|1412962730.893007|0*1|handle@000000000027EC60.async_read_some  
@asio|1412962730.905008|0*2|deadline_timer@000000000027EC60.async_wait  
@asio|1412962730.927009|>1|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=6  
@asio|1412962730.934009|1|deadline_timer@000000000027EC60.cancel  
@asio|1412962730.941010|<1|  
@asio|1412962730.944010|>2|ec=system:995  
@asio|1412962730.948010|<2|
```

When it is not working fine, I get this output:

```
@asio|1412963195.973608|0*3|handle@000000000027EC60.async_read_some  
@asio|1412963195.973608|0*4|deadline_timer@000000000027EC60.async_wait  
@asio|1412963195.976608|>3|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=0  
@asio|1412963195.981608|<3|  
@asio|1412963196.973665|>4|ec=system:0  
@asio|1412963196.976665|4|handle@000000000027EC60.cancel  
@asio|1412963196.977665|<4|
```

and my print statements result with:

```
Reading feedback on the serial port
start event loop
Function read_callback
Error Code: The operation completed successfully
Bytes transferred: 0
Serial Link : No data to read
Timeout fired.
Going to cancel the serial port
All operations on serial port cancelled
close event loop
```

---

I am able to reproduce the issue compiling for a x64 platform with the following code. There is no data on the serial channel (the device doesn't send anything so the `async_read` function shouldn't call to the `read_callback` function).

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING

#include <boost\asio.hpp>
#include <boost\bind.hpp>
#include <boost\thread.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SerialPort
{
public:
  SerialPort(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned int baud, const string& peripheral) : 
    io_service(io_service), port(io_service, peripheral)
  {
    if(!port.is_open())
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("The serial port is already open.");
      return;
    }

    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud));
    cout << ".. Serial Port " << peripheral << " opened" << endl;

    do_read(); 
  }

  void close()
  {
    do_close(boost::system::error_code());
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service;
  boost::asio::serial_port port;
  unsigned char buffer_read[6];

  void do_read()
  {
    boost::asio::async_read(port,boost::asio::buffer(buffer_read, 6), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(6), boost::bind(&SerialPort::read_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void read_callback(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if(error)
    {
      return;
    }
    if(!error && bytes_transferred == 0)
    {
      cout << "Unexpected behaviour: no error but 0 byte transferred. \n" << endl;
      return;
    }
    do_read();
  }

  void do_close(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if(error)
      cerr << "Error detected: " << error.message() << endl;
    port.close();
    cout << ".. Serial Port closed" << endl;
    return;
  }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    SerialPort motor(io_service, 9600, "COM5");

    boost::thread thread_motor(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));    

    system("pause");
    motor.close();
    thread_motor.join();

  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
  }

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**
I spent some time to improve my code. I reproduced the issue with the following code. I'm using Boost 1.56.0 and I compile for a x64 platform (Windows 7). I removed system("pause") and I tried to find a better way to use io_service.

For the serial port, I used to have a specific serial device. To make it easier to reproduce, I wrote a very simple code (running on an Arduino Due).

The funny thing is that the first call of async_read ends with the weird behavior I was talking about, the second call waits for data to arrive (so it's fine !).

Please feel free to comment my code:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING

#define SERIAL_TIMEOUT_MS 10000

#include <boost\asio.hpp>
#include <boost\bind.hpp>
#include <boost\thread.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SerialPort : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    SerialPort(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned int baud, const string& peripheral) : 
        io_service(io_service), port(io_service, peripheral), timeout_timer(io_service)
    {
            if(!port.is_open())
            {

                throw std::runtime_error("The serial port is already open.");
                return;
            }

            port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud));
            cout << "Serial Port " << peripheral << " opened." << endl;
    }

    void close()
    {
        io_service.post(boost::bind(&SerialPort::do_close, this, boost::system::error_code()));
    }

    void do_read()
    {
        cout << "..Do_read called." << endl;
        boost::asio::async_read(port,boost::asio::buffer(buffer_read, 6), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(6), boost::bind(&SerialPort::read_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        timeout_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(SERIAL_TIMEOUT_MS));
        timeout_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SerialPort::wait_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));  
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service;
    boost::asio::serial_port port;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timeout_timer;
    unsigned char buffer_read[6];

    void read_callback(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        cout << "..Read_callback called." << endl;
        if(error)
        {
            cerr << "Read_callback called with an error." << endl;
            do_close(error);
            return;
        }
        if(!error && bytes_transferred == 0)
        {
            cerr << ".. ..Unexpected behaviour: no error but 0 byte transferred. \n" << endl;
            //timeout_timer.cancel(); // THIS LINE SHOULD BE INSTEAD OF THE NEXT ONE
            do_read(); // NASTY SOLUTION TO GET IT WORKING
            return;
        }

        cout << ".. ..Bytes transferred: " << bytes_transferred << " bytes." << endl;
        cout << ".. ..Message: " << buffer_read[0] << buffer_read[1] << buffer_read[2] << buffer_read[3] << buffer_read[4] << buffer_read[5] << endl;
        timeout_timer.cancel(); 
        do_read();
    }

    void wait_callback(const boost::system::error_code& error) //Called when the timer's deadline expire
    {
        cout << "..Wait_callback called." << endl;
        if (error)
        {
            cout << ".. ..Timeout cancelled." << endl;
            if(error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) // if timer fired
                do_close(error); // close the serial port only if error is not "operation_aborted"
            return;
        }

        cout << ".. ..Timeout fired." << endl;
        port.cancel();  // Close all asynchronous operation with serial port. will cause read_callback to fire with an error
                        // Does io_service keep running ?
        cout << ".. ..All operations on serial port cancelled.\n" <<endl;
        return;
    }

    void do_close(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        cout << "..Do_close called" << endl;
        if(error)
            cerr << "Error detected: " << error.message() << endl;
        if(error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            return;
        timeout_timer.cancel(); 
        port.close();
        cout << "Serial Port closed" << endl;
        return;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        auto_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service)); 
            // to prevent io_service to stop if no work left

        SerialPort motor(io_service, 9600, "COM6");
        boost::thread thread_motor(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));        

        motor.do_read(); 

        cin.get();

        motor.close(); // close the serial port
        work.reset(); // wait for handlers to finish normally. io_service stops when no more work to do.
        thread_motor.join(); // delete the current thread

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    cout <<"Press any key to exit..."<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The Arduino code:

```
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    delay(5000);
    Serial.write("azerty");
}
```

---

Thank you very much for telling me what I'm doing wrong!

Alexis

Comment: did you try to unconditionally print the errorcode message? `if(!error) 
        cout << "Error Code: " << error.message() <<endl;` seems a little useless to me. Did you mean `if(error)`? I guess you might see the cause for your confusion in that status message

Comment: OK, I tried to print the errorcode message with the condition 'if(error)' and without any condition (you are right, my condition was a mistake...). Unfortunately, there is no error so it doesn't get in the 'if(error)' condition.

The output is:
Reading feedback on the serial port \n
start event loop
Function read_callback
Error Code: The operation completed successfully
Bytes transferred: 0
Serial Link : No data to read
Timeout fired.

Comment: At this point it's probably best to edit the question with the new information.

Comment: It may be worth enabling [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html) and creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Normally, if [`async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload2.html)'s completion handler is invoked with `0` bytes transferred, then either the buffer size was 0 or an error occurred.

Comment: I have not been able to duplicate the issue on *nix, and I do not have access to a Windows environment to pursue this further.  I did examine the relevant `win_iocp` Boost.Asio classes, MSDN documentation, and could not identify a flow that would cause this behavior.  Consider either using the latest official Boost release, analyze with a debugger, and/or using a select-based reactor by defining `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP` (this also enables portable socket cancellation).

Comment: I'm already using the latest official Boost release (1.56.0). I will dig into this issue.
I'm just wondering if that may come from the driver (USB-to-Serial adapter)...

Comment: Ah, I have had problems with most of those adapters and drivers.  I would not be surprised if the problem is a driver or hardware.

Comment: Like you can see in my edit, I did the test with an Arduino instead of my serial device (it is not using the same driver). The problem didn't go away unfortunately...

Comment: One of the answer has been deleted without any notice. What's happened ? He was urging me to look at the manual, I did it many times and I quoted what I thought was an important part of the documentation. He kept telling me I was misunderstanding it but he didn't give me any further information. I really want to know what I'm misunderstanding and why this turnaround...

Comment: The author deleted the answer.  Your understanding of the documentation is fine, as was your use of `io_service::run()` and initiating operations/work.

Comment: OK, thank you. Too bad he didn't take the time to explain his mistake.